# ASP.NET web package deployment security

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, iis-8, asp.net-development-serv

We don't want our client to share or misuse the deployed asp.net MVC package to other IIS server machines. we need the asp.net MVC package to only work on specific server machines.

Comment: This is a licensing question, not a security or packaging question. Licensing works the same, no matter the application type or stack. You need to add code to your application that ensures a valid license is present. There are a *lot* of ways to do that, with varying degrees of success

Comment: If you really want to restrict the use of your web app, the best choice is to actually host it yourself, eg on a cloud provider, and charge per user or usage. Licensing can always be bypassed, and makes using the application harder - just look at pirated games.

Answer (score 0):

I think in cases like this, the best approach is to include in the contract with your client these types of limitations. Something like "This software can only be used on the specified machines". But consult with a legal team if you can.

Otherwise, you can look into "Licensing Servers". You can try to build your own, but it's hard to develop and maintain the server infrastructure. As an alternative, you can check licensing as a Service. I know of https://keygen.sh/, but I believe there are others.